# one application of Riemann mapping -- regarding symmetry

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a simply connected area which is symmetric with respect to point $z_0$ and

$f(z)$ is the biholomorphic mapping from $G$ to the unit circle $D$ where $f(z_0) = 0$.

Show that the images of two points symmetric about $z_0$ must be symmetric about the origin.

I know that being symmetric about $z_0$ just means that $z_1 + z_2 = 2z_0$. And we need to show that $f(z_1) + f(z_2) = 0$ where $f(z_0) = 0$. Then I'm stuck... How to proceed? Guess I need to use some properties of the Riemann mapping?

Comment: Assume $z_0 = 0$ for notational simplicity. Consider $g(z) = -f(-z)$. You want to show $g = f$. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for you help... I was just being silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually it's quite simple.
Let $g(z) = -f(2z_0 - z)$ and use the uniqueness of the Riemann mapping...
And we're done.